# Skype closes immediately after opening

Tags: skype

My Skype stopped running since a few weeks ago, and it doesn't want to open. The process stays open for a while, then it just dies, without showing any UI.

There's no errors related to this issue in Event Viewer. I tried deleting %appdata%/Skype, but it didn't work. I tried with and without compatibility options, but it still didn't work.  Internet Explorer seems to run fine. I even reinstalled it a couple of times, but it still didn't work..

I could use the Windows 8 version, but it's one of worst things I've ever seen.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I'm running Windows 8 64bit, if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, I've uninstalled and reinstalled countless of times, but it still didn't work. @Wutnaut

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of "skype" you are using but this is the "desktop" version of skype I use as I hate the windows 8 version as well.
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12162/how-do-i-get-the-desktop-version-of-skype-windows-8-or-above

If so then...

~check for a beta version

~Try to temporarily disable your anti-virus or firewall software

Here is how to completely uninstall Skype (just back-up all important files and information that you feel is important to you).  This will remove all traces of the Skype application so you can install a "fresh" copy of Skype.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10634/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-skype-for-windows-desktop?frompage=search&fromSearchFirstPage=false&q=complete%20uninstall

~ download and run "ccleaner" or similiar to get rid of currupt files.

Reset Internet Explorer to Default

Regardless of the browser you set as default, as Skype uses Internet Explorer engines. You can also delete temp files, browsing history and clear cache. Also disable or remove any unused or bad IE add-ons or plugins.

best of luck

Comment: As I said, I deleted %appdata%/Skype, which included the shared.xml.